# How to get lowest value from a column without GROUP BY function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a CURSOR that runs a SQL query and gets results. Let's say the column goes 10,20,30 in values. I don't understand how I could get the least value without a GROUP BY function. I tried a for loop but that just iterates. I tried putting it in a collection, but when I call COLLECTION.FIRST, it always returns 1, even though 1 is not in the collection.

any suggestions would help.

If you need more info I will provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to have the minimum value as part of the result, a pure SQL solution could be something like this. By not including anything in the `OVER`, you get the whole set together.

```
WITH test_tab AS
 (SELECT LEVEL * 10 AS x FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10)
SELECT x
      ,MIN(x) OVER() AS min_x
  FROM test_tab;
```

If you want to retrieve the value from the first item in a collection instead, you were almost there. The `FIRST` call you did retrieves the first index, not the first value; it needs to be used as follows. If this is a collection of primitives, use this.

```
collection(collection.FIRST)
```

If it is a collection of the whole cursor's result set, just append the column name.

```
collection(collection.FIRST).column
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris. I know there wasn't a lot of info to go by but well done. I was doing collection.FIRST. Changed it to collection(collection.FIRST) and it pulled my 0. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Would you mind marking the answer as accepted so the question is resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Add a column `min_column` to the query you use for the cursor:

```
select column, min(column) over() AS min_column 
from table
```